# Use of undefined constant test & Undefined index

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I am having trouble understanding the error. what is wrong with the code? 
I have a database named "test" so I am not expected to define test like $test.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><title>SOmething</title></head>
<body>
   <form name="fm" method="POST" action="cafe.php">
      Customer ID:<input type="text" name="cus"><br>
      Food Name:<input type="text" name="food"><br>
      Order ID:<input type="text" name="order"><br>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$isMySQLConnected=mysql_connect("localhost","root");

if($isMySQLConnected){
    echo "We are Connected to MySQL<br>"; 
}

$isDBConnected=mysql_select_db(test);

if($isDBConnected){
    echo "We are Connected to Test DataBase"; 
}

$cus=$_POST['cus'];
$food=$_POST['food'];
$order=$_POST['order'];
?>
```

Error:

> We are Connected to MySQL
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test' in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\assign\cafe.php on line 6 We are Connected to Test
>   DataBase
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cus in C:\xampp\htdocs\assign\cafe.php on
>   line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined index: food in C:\xampp\htdocs\assign\cafe.php on
>   line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: order in C:\xampp\htdocs\assign\cafe.php on
>   line 12

Comment: `$isDBConnected=mysql_select_db(test);` assume typo and meant to be `$test` or 'test'?

Comment: You have to use `$isDBConnected=mysql_select_db('test');`

Comment: put **test** in single quotes plus the syntax you're using is deprecated.

Comment: The second part is saying that cus, food and order do not exist in the $_POST super global. Check they exist before trying to use them with `if(isset($_POST['order'], $_POST['']... )) {}`

Comment: Thanks it solved it but what about the index error? @JanRydrych

Comment: you cannot get form values with out submitting the form.